# Pass dropdown value from function to React.useEffect() on selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Goal:** I am trying to change the link inside the fetch() function with the value that comes from the dropdown.

**Attempts:**

1) I attempted passing the value to the function like `GetAPILinks(Link_from_dropdown)` and calling it in the onSelect function however I am getting an error stating: `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`

2) I have also tried other methods of passing it by storing it in a variable inside GetAPILinks but resulted in errors.

I am starting to believe I am approaching this all wrong. Any advice or help would be great!

**My Code:**

`This code will fetch the data from a hard coded link and renders a dropdown button that prints the selected values to the console.`

```
import React from 'react';
import { DropdownButton, Dropdown} from 'react-bootstrap';

const GetAPILinks = () => {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = React.useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://Random_API/Link_From_Dropdown_Goes_Here')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setApiData(data);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <DropdownButton id="dropdown-item-button" title="API Links" onSelect={function(evt){console.log(evt)}}>
        <Dropdown.Item as="button" eventKey='API_Link1'>Link 1</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item as="button" eventKey='API_Link2'>Link 2</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item as="button" eventKey='API_Link3'>Link 3</Dropdown.Item>
    </DropdownButton>          
  );
}

export default GetAPILinks;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close here. You should track another state value for the fetch Url. Tracking it in a local variable, or calling the function directly won't trigger your component to render when the values change.

```
const [fetchUrl, setFetchUrl] = useState(initialValue);
```

in your `onSelect` drop down you can set the value of the `fetchUrl` using the `setFetchUrl` function that the `useState` hook provides.

Now all that is left is to tell your `useEffect` hook that it needs to execute whenever the `fetchUrl` state value changes. You should add `fetchUrl` to the deps array.

It might look something like this:

```
const GetAPILinks = () => {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = React.useState([]);
  const [fetchUrl, setFetchUrl] = React.useState('');
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (fetchUrl) {
      fetch(fetchUrl)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          setApiData(data);
        });
    }
  }, [fetchUrl]);

  return (
    <DropdownButton id="dropdown-item-button" title="API Links" onSelect={(e)=>{setFetchUrl(e.target.eventKey)}}>
        <Dropdown.Item as="button" eventKey='API_Link1'>Link 1</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item as="button" eventKey='API_Link2'>Link 2</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item as="button" eventKey='API_Link3'>Link 3</Dropdown.Item>
    </DropdownButton>          
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

---

```
const GetAPILinks = () => {

const [apiData, setApiData] = React.useState([]);
const [url, setUrl] = React.useState(null);
React.useEffect(() => {
 if (url) {
  fetch('https://${url}`)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    setApiData(data);
  }});
}, [url]);

return (
<DropdownButton id="dropdown-item-button" title="API Links" 
    onSelect={evt=>setUrl(evt.key)}>
    <Dropdown.Item as="button" eventKey='API_Link1'>Link 
        1
    </Dropdown.Item>
  </DropdownButton>          
 );
}

 export default GetAPILinks;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create another state for current link and add it to `useEffect` dependencies.

It should be something like that, I didn't test.

```
import React from 'react';
import { DropdownButton, Dropdown} from 'react-bootstrap';

const GetAPILinks = () => {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = React.useState([]);
  const [currentLink, setCurrentLink] = React.useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://Random_API/${currentLink}`)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setApiData(data);
      });
  }, [currentLink]);

  return (
    <DropdownButton id="dropdown-item-button" title="API Links" onSelect={(e)=>{setCurrentLink(e.target.eventKey)}}>
        <Dropdown.Item as="button" eventKey='API_Link1'>Link 1</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item as="button" eventKey='API_Link2'>Link 2</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item as="button" eventKey='API_Link3'>Link 3</Dropdown.Item>
    </DropdownButton>          
  );
}

export default GetAPILinks;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add another piece of state to track the selected dropdown value

```
const [query, setQuery] = useState();
```

And add `query` to the dependency array of the effect and only make the fetch request when `query` is truthy

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  query && fetch(`https://Random_API/${query}`)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      setApiData(data);
    });
}, [query]);
```

[image: Edit mystifying-nash-wtfrc]

A cleaner solution may be to factor out the fetch logic to its own function, call that with the callback, and store only the result in state

```
const GetAPILinks = () => {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = query => fetch(`https://Random_API/${query}`)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(setApiData(data));

  return (
    <DropdownButton id="dropdown-item-button" title="API Links" onSelect={fetchData}>
        <Dropdown.Item as="button" eventKey='API_Link1'>Link 1</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item as="button" eventKey='API_Link2'>Link 2</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item as="button" eventKey='API_Link3'>Link 3</Dropdown.Item>
    </DropdownButton>          
  );
}
```